# How to implement a matching algorithm between users?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am implementing a matching algorithm in my application and I want to make sure that if one person matched to another person who already exist in a list person A will see the details of person B.

And also person B will see the details of person at the same time. How do I do that? My code is below. How can I modified my post request Route?

```
const { WaitingList } = require("../models/waitingList");
const auth = require("../middleware/auth");
const admin = require("../middleware/admin");
const validateObjectId = require("../middleware/validateObjectId");
const moment = require("moment");
const { User } = require("../models/user");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  let userId = req.body.userId;

  //---------find the first user on the waiting list
  let __lastWaitLister = await WaitingList.findOne(
    { completed: false, "from.2": { $exists: false } },
    {},
    { sort: { createdAt: 1 } }
  );

  if (__lastWaitLister) {
    //---------add the new user to the first users list

    let __updates = {
      $push: {
        from: {
          user: userId,
          status: "pending",
        },
      },
    };
    //---------check if this is the second person and take the first user off
    if (__lastWaitLister.from && __lastWaitLister.from.length === 1) {
      __updates["$set"] = {
        completed: true,
      };
    }

    //---------update the list
    await __lastWaitLister.updateOne(__updates);
  }
  //---------add the new user to the waiting list

  let new_waitList = new WaitingList({
    user: userId,
    from: [],
    completed: false,
    receipientInfor: [],
  });

  await new_waitList.save();
});

router.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const waitingList = await WaitingList.findById(req.params.id)
    .populate({ path: "user", select: "name  momoNumber" })
    .populate("from")
    .populate("from.user", "name momoNumber")
    .select(" completed  createdAt");
  res.send(waitingList);
});
router.delete("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  let __paidWaitList = await WaitingList.findOneAndDelete({
    "from.status": "paid",
  });

  if (!__paidWaitList) res.status(404).send("no record found"); //----------check if all users have made
  // )

  res.send(__paidWaitList);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: This sounds like you would like a reader to implement a feature for you. I doubt that someone will do that, as it is a lot of work, and it is not clear what you would consider a correct implementation anyway. Can you narrow down what you, personally, are stuck on?

Comment: As a general remark, it looks like you are merging your controller code with your business logic. This can make things rather hard to test. Ideally your router statements should contain a closure that is very short, and that code should just decode request/response inputs/outputs and feed it into/out of a service function/class. That will allow you to split up your logic into separate files too.